# Expected identifier in C

Tags: c, declaration

The error I'm getting is "expected identifier or '(' before float." Any help would be appreciated. I've read it might have to do with the semi colon after fprod? I've tried adding parenthesis like (float) fsum and (float) fprod, as well as removing the semi colon both with and without parenthesis.

```
int main (void)

{

int x, y, z, fx, fy, fz, sum, prod, float fsum, float fprod;
                                   //The error occurs on line 9. The above is line 9
    printf("\n Enter the first integer number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
            if( x<=0){
            printf("\n Invalid entry. Entry must be greater than 0.");
            scanf("%d",&x);
    }

    printf("\n Enter the second integer number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
            if( y<=0){
            printf("\n Invalid entry. Entry must be greater than 0.");
            scanf("%d",&y);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how a list of variables is supposed to look like. Each new *type* should start on a line of its own.

Comment: Please sort out the indentation and check the return value for `scanf`

Comment: @Jongware there is no such requirement about starting a new type on a new line. One can put how many declarations and statements on a single line. Even the entire program can be written on a single line.

Comment: You may also prefer a `do..while` loop instead of the naive check-once on wrong input.

Comment: @axiac: "line" in the context of C. The proper expression is *statement*.

Comment: @Jongware  He does not have new types. He uses well-known old types.:)

Comment: @jong we're to assume for this assignment that the user will only enter an invalid entry only once, but I'm aware of the issue that this would cause :)

Comment: @Jongware By the way strictly speaking in C declarations are not statements.:)

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare different types of variables in the same declaration.  Change

```
int x, y, z, fx, fy, fz, sum, prod, float fsum, float fprod;
```

to

```
int x, y, z, fx, fy, fz, sum, prod;
float fsum, fprod;
```

As some comments have pointed out, it's bad practice to just group all the variables into a single declaration. It's better to split them up based on function or locality.  This is really dependant on your program but you can do something like this:

```
int x, y, z;
int fx, fy, fz;
int sum, prod;
float fsum, fprod;
```

Also, it's a good idea to initialize your variables to some sane values since they will contain random undefined values and if you try to use them without successfully setting them, you could end up with hard to find bugs. So:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0; // or some other value if it makes sense
int fx = 0, fy = 0, fz = 0;
int sum = 0, prod  = 0;
float fsum = 0.0, fprod = 0.0;
```

Comment: One should note that packing all varibles of the same typ onto a single line is also bad style. Only group such variables which are related to each other (some coding styles even require one line per variable - I would not go that far).

Comment: @Olaf  I agree with you. It would be better to write i\n\t x, y, z, fx, fy, fz, sum, prod; :)
,

Comment: @olaf I'm very new to programming and this is how it was shown in lecture. So, to confirm the proper way would look like:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
etc, all on different lines?

Comment: @Geoff: the way you're doing it seems fine (after the correction) as long as all those variables are logically related to each other.  It's also a good idea to initialize the variables.  I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Geoff: That is just a suggestion! Well, but how programmers structure their code might be important if you want to get a job lateron. I for myself take formatting pretty serious - but not religious. I just would group them by functionality. Perhaps `int x, y, z;` `int fx, fy, fz;` ... But I would not criticize now. If you use documentation tools like Doxygen, you likely start using one line per var yourself, at least for documented vars.

Comment: @rost0031: I am not sure I agree with the initializers. As I enable most warnings, I'l likely get a warning once I forget to use a variable. But if I always initialize it, the warning is suppressed. Not sure if that is better. (OTOH, gcc gives me a warning if I use a var uninitialized - still better than an explicit initializer).

Comment: @Olaf: I'd much rather have a known value that I explicitly set and can check for if setting it doesn't go right than have gcc spitting out warnings about uninitialized variables.  Uninitialized variables lead to non-deterministic behavior: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223862/how-important-is-to-initialize-a-variable

Comment: @Olaf I mean splitting the line into three lines.:)

Comment: @rost0031: You missunderstood me: I do treat warnings like errors. So I do correct them instantly before I run my program unless I'm sure they are irrelevant for first debugging runs. Once unit testing start, there _are_ no warnings allowed anymore.

Comment: @Olaf: then why do you disagree with initializing the variables?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I did anticipate that, I just wonder about what you wrote. Never mind!

Comment: @olaf right, I understand it won't break the program if I don't do this but I also understand readability is always a huge concern. Best to learn it right! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would not initializing also potentially cause products and sums of these ints and floats  to read 0.00000?

Comment: @Geoff: as I said, what you initialize to really depends on your application.  You can initialize them to values that you KNOW shouldn't exist.  Maybe you know that you should never had a negative sum?  Initialize the sum to a negative number and check for it.  If negative = error.  Make sense?

Comment: @rost0031: " I am not sure I agree ..." - I did not say I disagree. I just cannot see if that would be better. During first tests when a function is not complete, I _do_ accept such warnings, but read them carefully. Once I deem the function complete, there are no warnings allowed anymore.

Comment: @Geoff: Variables defined inside a function are not initialized (for speed reasons). So, if you use them before they get a proper value, that is called _undefined behaviour_. Briefly: that is very, very bad and [daemons might fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @rost makes sense. That wasn't the issue. It has to be an issue with the float definition as my program works with int definitions

Comment: @Olaf yep, it's absolutely how I defined my float variables that's the issue. when a variable is defined correctly in a function elsewhere in my program it's highlighted as white. fsum and fprod are both currently red.  I'm thinking I must have missed some { somewhere...

Comment: @Geoff: I would not rely completely on the editor, but more on the compiler. But some editors use llvm to detect such issues, making that rule of me somewhat "floating". However, I think it is also a matter of experience and everyone has to develop her own style. I'm ok with it, if the style is consistent and has clear excalation rules. While I do use most warnings, I'm still careful trusting them completely.

Comment: @olaf I understand. Unfortunately its a logic error, not a compile error so the compiler is of no help here. Thanks!

Comment: @Geoff: Where did I claim it was a compile error (what would that be anyway?)?

Comment: @Geoff: Well, in the code you posted, you're missing a closing `}` bracket.

Comment: @rost0031: Fascinating editor: highlights uninitialized variables, but not missing brackets? :-)

Comment: @olaf I had assumed that the compiler would really only be helpful in figuring out compile errors, although it sounds like I'm wrong on that one! Haha I really don't think I missed a bracket. It will highlight closed brackets so its easy to line them up.

Comment: @rost0031 That was only a snippet of the program. This newest issue is much further down. I don't think a missing bracket is the issue here.

Comment: @Geoff: I assume rost meant the code as posted. I still wonder what a "compile error" is. The compiler primarily catches syntax or grammar errors and mostly warns about type errors (if enabled). It possibly can warn about much more possibly faults, if enabled.

Comment: @olaf its a syntax error. Yeah, I meant to say that I do have the curly brackets further down in my program. I only cut out an incomplete portion to show the bit I was having issues with initially

Comment: @Geoff: syntax error in the code that you posted (after the corrections have been applied) or somewhere?

Comment: There was one after. For both of you that have stuck with me this far I figured it out. I messed up my printf functions. I had printf("\n Product of the three float integers is %f\n, fprod");

I put the ending " mark in the wrong place. Only took me a good 2.5 hours to catch haha. Thanks again for all your help!